# Find the last position occurence of each item in an array

Tags: php

I have an array like this :

```
Array (
[0] => 2
[1] => 1
[2] => 3
[3] => 5
[4] => 1
[5] => 2
[6] => 1
[7] => 4
[8] => 2
...)
```

what i want to do is to find the last occurence of each item in this array in php
so this exemple will output :

```
Element|Position
   2   |   8
   1   |   6
   3   |   2
   5   |   3
   4   |   7
```

Is there a simple way to do that in php ? thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? What is the issue with your attempts at solving this?

Comment: An easy way would be to reverse the array and look for the first occurrence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$result = array();
foreach($array as $pos => $val)
{
   $result[$val] = $pos;
}
```

Using `$arr[$x] = $v` allows us to overwrite the new value for the existing key
or just adding a new key.

Now you can print the array:
(Just notice that in the "results" array the keys are the elements(numbers) and the values are the positions)

```
echo "Elements | Position (Last Occurrence)";
foreach($result as $val => $pos)
{
   echo $val." | ".$pos. "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[array_flip()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php)

> array_flip() returns an array in flip order, i.e. keys from array become values and values from array become keys.
>
> Note that the values of array need to be valid keys, i.e. they need to be either integer or string. A warning will be emitted if a value has the wrong type, and the key/value pair in question will not be included in the result.
>
> If a value has several occurrences, the latest key will be used as its value, and all others will be lost.

```
$positions = array_flip($data);

var_dump($positions);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this too , **`a one-liner solution.`**

```
<?php
$arr = array(2,1,3,5,1,2,1,4,2);// Your array
$arr2=array_flip(array_unique(array_reverse($arr,true))); // Yeah , a one-liner :)

//Displaying purposes....
foreach($arr2 as $k=>$v)
{
echo "$k is in $v position<br>";
}
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
2 is in 8 position
4 is in 7 position
1 is in 6 position
5 is in 3 position
3 is in 2 position
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will give you the desired associative array.

```
$array = array(2, 5, 4, 6 , 2, 6); //Set of numbers
$occurences = array(); 

foreach($array as $i => $value){
  if (isset($occurences[$value])){
    $occurences[$value]['position'] = $i ;
  } else {
    $occurences[$value] = array(
      "position" => $i,
      "element"  => $value
    );
  }
}

var_dump($occurences);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$array = array("1", "2", "1", "3", "2", "1", "1", "1" , "4");
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
?>
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 2
    [5] => 1
    [6] => 1
    [7] => 1
    [8] => 4
)

$x = array_count_values($array);
ksort($x);
foreach ($x as $key => $value){
echo $key .'|'. $value ."<br>";     
}
```

Output

```
2|2
3|1
4|1
```